# How to setup AWS CDK app execution in AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to run AWS CDK synthesis from Git repository using AWS CodeBuild - i.e. if I update the CDK app code in the repo I want CloudFormation stacks to be updated automatically. What are the best practices for setting up build role permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a GitHub repository, your CodeBuild role doesn't need additional permissions but it should have access to an `oauthToken` to access GitHub.

For a CodeCommit repository, create or `import` a `codecommit.Repository` object and use a `CodeCommitSource` object for your `source` parameter, and the build role permissions will be set up automatically (in particular, the permissions that will be added will be to [`codecommit:GitPull`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-codebuild/lib/source.ts#L96) from the indicated repository).

See [here](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.html).

You might also be interested in CDK's [app-delivery](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/app-delivery) package. It doesn't just create a CodeBuild project though, it uses CodePipeline to fetch, build and deploy a CDK application, so it might be more than you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, app-delivery package looks like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

AWS released a month ago a new class to the CDK suite called [pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/pipelines-readme.html) that includes several utilities to ease the job of setting up self modifying pipelines. In addition, there's [codepipeline-actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-codepipeline-actions-readme.html) that includes constructs to hook your pipeline to CodeCommit, GitHub, BitBucket, etc...

Here's a complete [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/) (verbatim from the linked blog post), using github as a source, that deploys a lambda through CodePipeline:

Create a stage with your stack

```
import { CfnOutput, Construct, Stage, StageProps } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { CdkpipelinesDemoStack } from './cdkpipelines-demo-stack';

/**
 * Deployable unit of web service app
 */
export class CdkpipelinesDemoStage extends Stage {
  public readonly urlOutput: CfnOutput;
  
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StageProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const service = new CdkpipelinesDemoStack(this, 'WebService');
    
    // Expose CdkpipelinesDemoStack's output one level higher
    this.urlOutput = service.urlOutput;
  }
}
```

Create a stack with your pipeline

```
import * as codepipeline from '@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline';
import * as codepipeline_actions from '@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions';
import { Construct, SecretValue, Stack, StackProps } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { CdkPipeline, SimpleSynthAction } from "@aws-cdk/pipelines";

/**
 * The stack that defines the application pipeline
 */
export class CdkpipelinesDemoPipelineStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const sourceArtifact = new codepipeline.Artifact();
    const cloudAssemblyArtifact = new codepipeline.Artifact();
 
    const pipeline = new CdkPipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      // The pipeline name
      pipelineName: 'MyServicePipeline',
      cloudAssemblyArtifact,

      // Where the source can be found
      sourceAction: new codepipeline_actions.GitHubSourceAction({
        actionName: 'GitHub',
        output: sourceArtifact,
        oauthToken: SecretValue.secretsManager('github-token'),
        owner: 'OWNER',
        repo: 'REPO',
      }),

       // How it will be built and synthesized
       synthAction: SimpleSynthAction.standardNpmSynth({
         sourceArtifact,
         cloudAssemblyArtifact,
         
         // We need a build step to compile the TypeScript Lambda
         buildCommand: 'npm run build'
       }),
    });

    // This is where we add the application stages
    // ...
  }
}
```